# Best Practices for building restful api service using spring boot with jwt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, software-design

I would like to know if there is best practices for building restful api service using spring boot with jwt.
I was watching udemy lectures: https://github.com/in28minutes/full-stack-with-react-and-spring-boot

It is a just toy example using h2.. but I'm going to use mysql.

I have difficulty structuring the project. service model... dto .. config ... I wonder if there is a best practice for it... like template....

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWBxh.png)

I moved lots files from jwt folder to each categories that I think these are belong.
But any suggestions and opinions are welcome.

Thank you for reading my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro If u want to know in depth about security in spring boot with

1. Roles at Different levels
2. JWT

I gone through many resource but amigoscode on youtube is best for spring security
Below is the link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg